# HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo In webservice returns empty

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have created a web service ".asmx". I have a private function in web service and is being called by all other functions to log information about client that is connected to a specific function!

I am using

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo
```

for getting its function name.

It is working in web browser and return function name. But when I reference it in a program and call one of its functions, it will return empty.

This is how I call it:

```
FarshadWebServiceSoapClient F = new FarshadWebServiceSoapClient();
F.GetHospitalInfo();
```

and this is the web service code:

```
public HospitalModel GetHospitalInfo()
{ 
    GetRequestInfo();

    LogHandler.InsertLogIntoDb(ip: Config.IP,funcName: Config.FuncName);
}

private static void GetRequestInfo()
{
    Config.FuncName = HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo;
    Config.IP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName;
}
```

**Update 1:**

I think this assembly is using soap and Post.But web browser is using Get i think. Because of visiting /GetHospitalInfo page, you will get answer from PathInfo.
Is there any way to catch it in that way?

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture html messages with web browser that works.  Then compare with app that is not working.  Make not working code look like working code by adding missing http headers.

Comment: I think this assembly is using soap and Post.But web browser is using get i think. Be cause of visiting /GetHospitalInfo, you will get answer from PathInfo @jdweng

Comment: Do not think.  Use the sniffer.

Comment: @jdweng , I have used wireshark and did display filtering like ip.dst == "192.168.1.1"(Mylocal IP) But no result. Is there any special setting to set?

Comment: Filter on the http packets.Then look at the HEADERS.  You want to look at both receive messages and transmit messages so if you filter on IP make sure you are getting both source and destination IP.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer so a HTTP will  consist of one or more TCP datagrams.  The sniffer shows both HTTP and TCP, but you can ignore the TCP right now.  The only time you have to look at the TCP is if the connection is closing to help figure out why a connetion closes.  Usually you just have to add missing headers to the c# app that are in the working IE.